# Magento use two different Taxes to different Product

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I'm creating a WebShop with Magento. My question is, is it possible to use a different Tax for a different Product.

I have a wine product and an eatables product; for the wine products I have a Tax of 8% and for the eatable product I have a Tax of 2%.

Now I have created two of these Tax rules in the Backend going under .. Sales -> Tax that looks like this:

[image]

Then I  go to System -> Config -> Sales -> Tax, and there will be the problem I think. In the Dropdown Menu I can use only one of the two Tax rates I have created, but I need both.

The Calculation settings:

[image]

Have you an idea how to resolve this? Can I Configure that or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to use two different tax. You have to install the Modul FireGento. than you can configure it for Swiss Tax Classes or German.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure I understand what you want, but for each product

- go to Catalog/Manage Product/*/Prices
- then you can choose the tax class

Comment: Yes i have done this. I have two Tax classes. 1 of this is 8% the other is 2% .  So if i add the one product with 8 % in my shoppingcart and one product with 2% in the bill i only see the taxrate of 8% and the taxrate of 2% is not there.

Comment: Could you tell me what you have in "Calculation settings" please ?

Comment: I have add an image in my question. I think the problem is in the "Tax Class for Shipping" becaus i can only choose one of this two Tax Class. "Wein MwSt." is 8% but i need to choose  the other two..

Comment: Sorry I hadn't see this one. So could you try to change "Tax Calculation Method Based On" to "unit price" and "Tax Class for Shipping" to "none" ?

Comment: it doesent work. hmm.. whene i make a tax rule with both tax classes they are only put the tax with 8% for all products.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many product class you have created , Magento allows any one Tax class for shipping. Multilple tax class can not be selected.